# Which sites on Stack Exchange overlap most with Vegetarianism.SE?

Tags: discussion, faq, stackexchange

Which StackExchange sites are most closely related to Vegetarianism.SE? This should be a handy list for a few different scenarios.

- We might want to mention them on the [on-topic](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page in our help center.
- Likely targets for migrations that aren't quite on-topic.
- Places we might want to place [community ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237281/community-ads-faq).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)** (Cooking.SE)

> This site is for professional and amateur cooks and chefs, and anyone else who works in the kitchen or is interested in preparing and serving delicious meals.

**[Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/)** (Sustainability.SE)

> Sustainable Living Stack Exchange is for folks dedicated to a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources.

**[Physical Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/)** (Fitness.SE)

> Physical Fitness Stack Exchange is for fitness professionals, athletes, trainers and enthusiasts.

**[Gardening & Landscape](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/)** (Gardening.SE)

> This site is for professional and amateur gardeners and landscapers to ask questions about the care and maintenance of gardens and landscapes.

**[Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/)** (Pets.SE)

> At a high level, this site is about pets and by that we mean an animal companion that is cared for in a domestic setting and not livestock, wildlife, and pests in and around your home.

**[Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/)** (MedicalSciences.SE)

> If your question is about...
>
> - clinical guidelines
> - disease prevention and management
> - human physiology and pathophysiology
> - pharmacology
> - diagnostic and prognostic methods
> - public health
> - medical research
>     ... then this is the right place to ask.

**[Interpersonal Skills (Beta)](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/)**

> looking to improve their interpersonal communication skills

Comment: Everyone - feel free to edit this. (It's community wiki, not that it matters on Meta.)

Comment: "It's community wiki, not that it matters on Meta." - That does still matter, actually, because "suggested edits" aren't possible on Meta otherwise; only those with full editing privileges can edit others' posts on Meta.

Comment: @V2Blast Thanks! I didn't know that.